# How to increase Sattva guna?

Tags: gunas

There are 3 gunas - Sattva, Rajas, Tamas.

There are 5 jnana indriyas - hear, touch, see, taste, smell

and 5 karma indriyas - hands, feet, speech, procreation, waste

These above 10 are our only means of interacting with the world. And in the world, there are many items which have a mixture of above 3 gunas, some dominating others.

Question is - For each of the above organs of knowledge and action, what are the corresponding stimuli that will increase Satva guna in the person ?

e.g.
For ears - hearing Bhagavan's Nama increases Sattva.
For hands - doing puja increases Sattva

Our senses constantly ask for gratification. It is very hard to sit still and do nothing. But doing whatever the senses please also leads us further down in samsara because most attractions are filled with Rajas + Tamas. On the other extreme, it is also hard to be engaged in devotion all the time like saints, since most people are *loukikas*

So, since it's not easy to 'slay' the senses, how to engage all 5 senses constantly in such a way that only Sattva guna predominates
i.e. what are all the Satvik attractions available for a wordly-minded person ?

Comment: God live in every human, animal, insect etc. Try to see everyone as form of God. If one can see God in every bieng then he don't need to worry about his Satvik Progress coz in such state you will always talk with God, walk with God, eat with God. Even when no one with you, then also God is inside you too. So you are never alone. Try to feel Presence of your God inside you all time. (just an opinion)

Comment: i think starting point would be to associate with sattvik personalities and sattvik food.

Comment: The secret lies  not in learning subject but in implementing those issues in our Life. That brings improvement (https://www.purebhakti.com/teachers/bhakti-discourses/24-discourses-2005/462-your-twenty-four-gurus)